# Where should I put code that I want to always run for each request?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

Maybe this is more of an ASP.NET MVC question than an Orchard question but I'm relatively new to both and I don't know the answer in either case.

ASP.NET MVC applications don't technically have a single point of entry, so where am I supposed to put code that I want to always run each and every time someone visits any page, regardless of layer or origin or permissions? Is there a specific Orchard way of doing this?

If it makes a difference, what I'm specifically trying to do at the moment is to restrict the IP range that has access to my website. I want to look at every incoming request and check if the user is either authenticated or has an IP in the allowed range that I configured in my custom settings.

I can think of some quick and dirty ways to achieve this like putting the check in `Layout` and wrap a condition around all of my zones or implement `IThemeSelector` to switch to a different Theme but I'd like to do it properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All what should you do to achieve this, is implementing new `IActionFilter` or `IAuthorizationFilter` like the following:

```cs
public class CheckAccessFilter : FilterProvider, IActionFilter, IAuthorizationFilter {
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        // here you can check the incoming request, and how the system will deal with it,
        // before executing the action
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {

    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        // here you can authorize any request
    }
}
```

But if you want only to authorize based on content items (like: Widgets, Pages, Projections), you can implement `IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler`:

```cs
public class IPAuthorizationEventHandler : IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler {
    public void Checking(CheckAccessContext context) { 
    }

    public void Adjust(CheckAccessContext context) { 
    }

    public void Complete(CheckAccessContext context) { 
    }
}
```

The best sample you can follow to implement this approach is `SecurableContentItemsAuthorizationEventHandler`, you can find it in `Orchard.ContentPermissions` module.

Comment: This answered my question about where to put such code. However, I now have the problem that I can't redirect in the `OnResultExecuting` method if my check fails because "Cannot redirect after HTTP Headers have already been set". Any idea if there is a way around this?

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake, please see the updated answer, should use 'IActionFilter' rather than 'IResultFilter' to catch the request before process the action itself.

Comment: Cheers, everything I wanted to know and more!